# In pulumi, how can I get the fully qualified resource type name?

Tags: pulumi

I'd like to be able to generate an urn based on the current stack, project and resource type. This would be handy when renaming resources, where the `aliases` options requires a full urn to make the link between resources.

I've got the following:

```
`urn:pulumi:${pulumi.getStack()}::${pulumi.getProject()}::kubernetes:storage.k8s.io/v1:StorageClass::cluster-enable-ssd`
```

I'd like to generate the `kubernetes:storage.k8s.io/v1:StorageClass` part given an arbitrary pulumi Resource class, e.g. in this case `k8s.storage.v1.StorageClass`.  The Resource class itself has `name` on it, but that only returns `StorageClass`.

Is there any way to get the global, unique identifier for a pulumi Resource type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hacky but you can get it like this (in Node.js):

```
(k8s.storage.v1.StorageClass as any).__pulumiType
```